# subclass scipy's rv_continuous with custon function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to create a subclass of rv_continuous with ad hoc distribution.
I have an expression for the pdf, and I want to draw random numbers from it. However, I cannot even obtain a plot of the pdf. The code that I post shows that I'm obtaining NaNs when I call `dist.pdf`, while calling `dist._pdf` gives me the correct answer (inside the bounds I set).

Here is a simple example, the print functions should return the same output, while the last one is giving only NaNs. I'm quite sure I'm passing some parameters to `dist.pdf` in the wrong way, but I'm not an expert of scipy.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import division, print_function
import numpy as np

# the actual function used to compute the pdf
def _schechter(M, alpha, phi, Mo):
    f = phi * 10.0**(0.4 * (alpha + 1) * (Mo - M))
    out = 0.4 * np.log(10.0) * np.exp(-10.0**(0.4 * (Mo - M))) * f
    return out

from scipy import stats
class sch(stats.rv_continuous):
    def _pdf(self, x, alpha, phi, Mo):
        return _schechter(x, alpha, phi, Mo)

# to normalize the distribution, it has to be limited on the right, b cannot be
# np.inf
dist = sch(name='schecter', b=0.)


x_real = np.linspace(-100, -1, 100)
print(_schechter(x_real , -1.4, 1., -21))
print(dist._pdf(x_real, alpha=-1.4, phi=1., Mo=-21))
print(dist.pdf(x_real, -1.4, 1., -21.))
```

Can someone help me?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

My issue was fairly simple: as stated by the documentation

*If positive argument checking is not correct for your RV then you will also need to re-define the _argcheck method.*

By redefining the _argcheck function I got it to work.

```
def _argcheck(self, *args):
    """Default check for correct values on args and keywords.
    Returns condition array of 1's where arguments are correct and
     0's where they are not.
    """
    cond = 1
    for arg in args:
        cond = np.logical_and(cond, (np.asarray(arg) > -np.inf))
    return cond
```

Answer (score 0):

@andrea dist.pdf has the following arguments. Please check doc strings for more info.

```
Signature: dist.pdf(x, *args, **kwds)
Docstring:
Probability density function at x of the given RV.

Parameters
----------
x : array_like
    quantiles
arg1, arg2, arg3,... : array_like
    The shape parameter(s) for the distribution (see docstring of the
    instance object for more information)
loc : array_like, optional
    location parameter (default=0)
scale : array_like, optional
    scale parameter (default=1)
```

Comment: Indeed there is written that `shape parameters will be inferred from the signature of the private methods, _pdf and _cdf of the instance.` so my  implementation should be ok, but it returns NaN instead